# Getting list of running containers from a cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, containers, amazon-ecs

I am running docker containers on an AWS via ECS. I have setup a cluster with some basic configuration.

Now I am looking forward to get no. of all running containers on this cluster (spread across 2-3 EC2 instances)? Does AWS / Docker provide any API for this?

I know on a container instance, doing `docker ps -a` will return me list of all running / stopped containers, while `docker ps` will return running containers on one system. But I want an API (which can be called from outside) or command (which I can run on any of the instance part of the cluster) and it shows me total number of running containers across cluster?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In ECS you're looking at tasks. You can list all running tasks with the ECS API. With the aws cli, for example, you can do:

```
aws ecs list-tasks --cluster <cluster_name>
```

If you use one of the SDKs, for example boto3, you can obtain the count easily:

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('ecs')

tasks = client.list_tasks(cluster='YouCluster')

print(len(tasks['taskArns'])
```

Comment: Yes. It does the trick. Thanks 

Previously I was trying this but it was not returning anything and I thought something is missing. It was not returning anything because it only returns the actively running tasks.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure of getting the containers information in AWS environment. But **Docker has a very good support for API** in the single server or in running the cluster, especially cluster with [Docker Swarm](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/key-concepts/).

For **using docker API you need to configure the docker daemon port on the manager node in the cluster**(if the cluster is running in docker swarm) or configure all the nodes individually and can access the APIs.

There are **2 ways in configuring the docker daemon port**

1) Configuring at **/etc/default/docker file:**

```
DOCKER_OPTS="-H tcp://127.0.0.1:5000 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
```

2) Configuring at **/etc/docker/daemon.json**:

```
{
"hosts": ["tcp://127.0.0.1:6000", "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"]
}
```

Restart the docker service once the port is configured.

If the docker default socket(unix:///var/run/docker.sock) is not configured, Docker may not have configured properly and will wait for infinite period.

**NOTE : BUT DON'T CONFIGURE IN BOTH THE CONFIGURATION FILES**, the following error may occur :

```
Waiting for /var/run/docker.sock
unable to configure the Docker daemon with file /etc/docker/daemon.json: the following directives are specified both as a flag and in the configuration file: hosts: (from flag: [tcp://127.0.0.1:5000 unix:///var/run/docker.sock], from file: tcp://127.0.0.1:5000)
```

The reason for adding both the ***user port[ tcp://127.0.0.1:5000]*** and ***default docker socket[unix:///var/run/docker.sock]*** is that the user port enables the access to the docker APIs whereas the default socket enables the CLI. In case the default port[unix:///var/run/docker.sock] is not mentioned in /etc/default/docker file the following error may occur:

```
#docker ps
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

This error is not because that the docker is not running, **but because of default docker socket is not enabled.**

Once you have enabled the Docker daemon port you can access the **services running the cluster with Docker API**:

> curl -X GET http://127.0.0.1:6000/services?id=all

Or **API for individual servers** with:

> curl -X GET http://127.0.0.1:6000/containers/json?all

For more docker APIs refer [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.28/)

**NOTE: Tested for Docker Version 17.04 and Docker Swarm**.

To check the information through CLI in the cluster:

**Cluster information:**

```
#docker node ls
ID                           HOSTNAME                STATUS  AVAILABILITY  MANAGER STATUS
7pl9bab4g2yjwctjxq2aax3ud    radisysuser-VirtualBox  Ready   Active        
o45wire6qhu8i5eujl6iyon2p *  labadmin-VirtualBox     Ready   Active        Leader
odwdr5uey085hpb8tnwtj11e0    radisysuser-VirtualBox  Ready   Active
```

**Services/containers info:**

```
# docker service ls
ID                  NAME                MODE                REPLICAS            IMAGE
sccuf1jgkphn        redis               replicated          3/3                 redis:latest
```

**Individual services info:**

```
# docker service ps redis
ID                  NAME                IMAGE               NODE                     DESIRED STATE       CURRENT STATE                     ERROR               PORTS
jgix9p141pxt        redis.1             redis:latest        radisysuser-VirtualBox   Running             Running less than a second ago                        
1i4yc8f9cqm5        redis.2             redis:latest        radisysuser-VirtualBox   Running             Running less than a second ago                        
dk1tubki2dg8         \_ redis.2         redis:latest        radisysuser-VirtualBox   Shutdown            Shutdown less than a second ago                       
stpl55l6wwci        redis.3             redis:latest        labadmin-VirtualBox      Running             Running 4 hours ago
```

Hope this will helpful.